# How to do a preg_replace on return statements and add brackets if needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a PHP source code stored in a variable in which i want to do a replacement with a regular expression.

I want to append a custom method call in front of each `return` statement that exists in the source code.

Currently i'm doing that like so:

```
<?php
$code = '
class SomeClass
{
    public function TestMethod ( )
    {
        $count = 0;
        if ( $count = 2 )
            return false;

        if ( $count == 4 )
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function TestMethod ( )
    {
        return SomeCalculatedValue (4 + 10 );
    }
} ';

$code = preg_replace ( '~return~', 'someFunc(); return', $code );

echo '<pre>';
echo $code;
echo '</pre>';
```

This basically works. The only problem i have is `return` statements like this one:

```
if ( $count = 2 )
    return false;
```

This `return` isn't encapsulated in any curly brackets, which makes this:

```
if ( $count = 2 )
    someFunc(); return false;
```

Not the same as this:

```
if ( $count = 2 ) {
    someFunc(); return false;
}
```

So basically what i want to do is to add these brackets if they are missing.

I know you can do a 'look ahead' and 'look behind' (though i'm still uncomfortable with them) with regex to determine if the brackets are there. But is there then also a way to add the brackets if there are missing inside a `preg_replace`?

Anyone any idea how to do this?

[Demo can be found here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7yW8HD)

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an easy answer to this, since parens and brackets can be used for many things.. perhaps you should try approaching this differently

Comment: for example, instead of trying to inject `someFunc()` as a separate expression before the `return`, do a preg_replace on `return([^;]*)` to be `return someFunc($1);` (pseudocode).  Then have `someFunc()` return something based on what is passed to it (the stuff that comes after the original `return`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not capture the complete return line and always use curly braces in replaced text like this:

```
$code = preg_replace ( '/(return\s*[^;]*;)/i', '{ someFunc(); $1 }', $code );
```

**OUTPUT:** for your input:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function TestMethod ( )
    {
        $count = 0;
        if ( $count = 2 )
            { someFunc(); return false; }

        if ( $count == 4 )
        {
            { someFunc(); return; }
        }
    }

    public function TestMethod ( )
    {
        { someFunc(); return SomeCalculatedValue (4 + 10 ); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do great aswell!